# for Loop: iterating over one value of a list at a time in Python

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, iteration, range

My problem is that I want to loop over each element of the list one at a time. To elaborate, my list values are, for example, [60, 87, 51]. For the first iteration, I want to iterate over the range of 1 to 60, in the second iteration over the range of 1 to 87, and in the third iteration over the range of  1 to 51.

I tried this code, but every time an error pops-up.

```
my_list = [60, 87, 51]

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

entries = []
for i in range(1, 4): 
    for j in my_list:
            driver.get('https://plato.stanford.edu/contents.html#a')
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="content"]/ul[1]/li[{i}]/a').click()
            content = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="main-text"]/p[{j}]').text
            entries.append([content])
driver.close()
```

Comment: Your loops should be `for i in my_list:` / `for j in range(1,i+1):`.  Or, if you really need the "1,2,3" values, do `for i in (1,2,3):` / `for j in range(1,my_list[i-1]+1):`.

Answer (score 2):

This will get the values you're looking for

```py
my_list = [60, 87, 51]
for i in my_list:
   for j in range(1, i+1):
      print(j)
```

Comment: Thanks for this is helpful! However, when I run it, I still do not get exactly what I want. 

The final output that I have in mind is:

web1
entry1
conten1
conten2
entry2
conten1
conten2
conten3
entry3
conten1
conten2
conten3
conten4
web2
entry1
conten1
conten2
conten3
conten4
conten5
... 


content_in_each_entry = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for k in range (1, 3):
    print(f'web{k}')
    for x in range (1, 4):
        print(f'entry{x}')
        for i in content_in_each_entry:
            for j in range(1, i+1):
                print(f'conten{j}')